# How to keep integrity on soft delete?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following situation: I have a system where one entity is related to another entities in most cases (40% of the system).

I'm using Entity Framework, where I can retrieve only items with certain property (e.g `IsDeleted`) equals false, which means, retrieve the data correctly, I'm able to do and it's ok.

But, I'm trying to figure out how I can check if there's another registry related to my principal entity BEFORE do the soft deletion. Since I have more than 450 entities on my system, it's not a option do a validation by hand on every table.

There's anything, configuration, flags... that I can perform this validation?

Comment: I would look into reflection for this task. I don't know of anything built in. Just iterate over the virtual properties of the object(s) in question and check for nulls.